# Is aluminum Underground Service Entrance cable safe for a 200 ampere service?

Tags: electrical

I am upgrading my power to 200 amps. My electrician wants to use 4/0 aluminum wire (instead of copper wire) from the meter loop, to the service panel located inside my mobile home. Is aluminum a safe choice?

Comment: What's the distance? For large conductors that are professionally installed aluminum is a very sensible choice, as it costs much less than copper, even though it must be a larger size to carry the same current as copper. So long as it is properly terminated (which should be a given with a pro handling it), it's perfectly safe.

Comment: The power company uses aluminum wire to deliver the power from the generator to your meter. You shouldn't have any concerns about more AL going from the meter to the panel.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. For service conductors aluminum is perfectly acceptable and typical in many/most places. AL conductors of today are not the same as they were 40 years ago, and the problems associated with AL were typically with smaller conductors, #12 & #10 solid.

Comment: Yes, here's a good article on where AL house wiring went wrong, and why it's not a problem today. http://www.southwire.com/commercial/AluminumBuildingWireHistory.htm